# Plotting vector field for first order differential equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, field

I'm trying to plot the direction fields for a simple velocity equation. I understand what I have to do when I'm working with two variables. I can understand the vector I have to create, but I don't understand how to do it for only one variable. My program is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def modelo2(y, t):
    dydt = 32 - 0.16 * y
    return dydt

t0 = 0 ; tf = 25 ; h = 0.1
t = np.arange(t0,tf+h,h)

for y0 in np.arange(0, 400, 25):
    
        y = odeint(modelo2,y0,t )
        plt.plot(t,y,'b')

x = np.arange(0, 400, 20)
z = np.arange(0, 400, 20)
X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
U = modelo2(X,t)
V = modelo2 (Z, t)

plt.quiver(X, Z, U, V, scale = 70)
plt.quiver(X, Z, U, V, scale = 60)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.axis([0,20,0, 500])
plt.show()
```

I get this

[image: 1]

When I expect something like this

[image: 2]

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have just posted it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
U = modelo2(X,t)
V = modelo2 (Z, t)
```

to this

```
U = 1.0
V = modelo2(Z, None)
N = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
U /= N
V /= N
```

As you can see you defined `U` wrong. Diving both `U` and `V` by `N` is necessary to normalise the magnitude of the vectors, otherwise their length in the plot will vary according to the strength of the field at each point. Just set `U = np.ones(Z.shape)` and don't divide either by `N` to see what I'm talking about.

Secondly, you need to set the following argument in `plt.quiver()`

```
plt.quiver(X, Z, U, V, angles='xy')
```

From the docs:

> ```
> angles : {'uv', 'xy'} or array-like, optional, default: 'uv'
>     Method for determining the angle of the arrows.
>
>     - 'uv': The arrow axis aspect ratio is 1 so that
>       if *U* == *V* the orientation of the arrow on the plot is 45 degrees
>       counter-clockwise from the horizontal axis (positive to the right).
>
>       Use this if the arrows symbolize a quantity that is not based on
>       *X*, *Y* data coordinates.
>
>     - 'xy': Arrows point from (x, y) to (x+u, y+v).
>       Use this for plotting a gradient field, for example.
>
>     - Alternatively, arbitrary angles may be specified explicitly as an array
>       of values in degrees, counter-clockwise from the horizontal axis.
>
>       In this case *U*, *V* is only used to determine the length of the
>       arrows.
>
>     Note: inverting a data axis will correspondingly invert the
>     arrows only with ``angles='xy'``.
> ```

---

All in all, your code should look like this (with some minor variable name edits):

```
def modelo2(y, t):
    dydt = 32 - 0.16 * y
    return dydt

t0, tf, h = 0, 25, 0.1
t = np.arange(t0, tf+h, h)
ymin, ymax, ystep = 0, 400, 25
y = np.arange(ymin, ymax+ystep, ystep)

for y0 in y:
    line = odeint(modelo2, y0, t)
    plt.plot(t, line, 'b')

x = np.linspace(t0, tf, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

U = 1
V = modelo2(Y, None)
N = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
U /= N
V /= N

plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, angles='xy')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.axis([t0, tf, ymin, ymax])
plt.show()
```

Result

[image: 1]